# Is It Ethical to Disturb a Happy Illusion for the Sake of Reality?

Tags: ethics

In 'The Matrix', Morpheus frees individuals from a simulated reality.  Some of them become unhappy - Cypher wants to go back and forget everything. Neo at first isn't very unhappy either.

From a utilitarian perspective, one might argue that if an individual is happy in their ignorance, disrupting their peace for the sake of 'reality' could create unnecessary suffering, and hence, would be unethical. From a deontological viewpoint, however, one could argue that individuals have a right to the truth, irrespective of the consequences.

**Is it morally right to disrupt someone's happiness to offer them the truth, even if it might cause distress?**

Also Morpheus doesn't fully disclose that once someone chooses the Red Pill, there's no possibility of returning to the Matrix.This raises another question:

**Was Morpheus morally justified in not completely informing individuals about the irreversible consequences of their choice?**

From an ethical standpoint, how critical is the principle of full disclosure in the process of informed consent? Could Morpheus' actions be seen as a violation of this principle, or can his actions be justified in any way?

**How might different ethical theories approach and interpret Morpheus' decisions?**

Comment: [Since Mill](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mill-moral-political/#HapHigPle), utilitarians distinguish "higher pleasures" that no bliss in ignorance can beat, and those are only available under full capacity. It is trickier if the incapacity is voluntarily chosen while in full capacity, or, as with the red pill, the choice is irreversibly taken away. The answer will depend on comparing "pleasures" of different "quality", but Morpheus may well take ignorant bliss to be so low "quality" and corrupting for the chooser that his actions are still justified.

Comment: Neo sought out Morpheus and the knowledge of the Matrix, it wasn't just inflicted on him. Sure, Neo was upset when he realized the extent of how deluded he had been, you couldn't expect him to just go, "Huh." Learning is always irreversible. Also, I am pretty sure that Morpheus did explain, as best he could, that the red pill was irreversible, by saying that the blue pill was the route back to Neo's known life. But Neo had already almost gotten out of the car on the way there. He had opportunities to change his mind. Also, Neo was not just himself, he was able to change life for billions.

Comment: Well, Morpheus wouldn't mind to unplug billions, many of them live very happy life. After being unplugged they'll get into much harsher reality. Also what he told Neo was very vague. He could tell him much more.

Comment: I think there's a good question here, but at the moment this seems a bit too heavily focused on cinematic analysis for this site. Morpheus and Neo both performed a very specific set of actions, within a very specific world, with specific consequences for those actions. All of that would apply to Morpheus' decisions, which is what you're asking about, rather than asking about the general idea of disturbing an illusion with the truth.

Comment: I use the movie as a setting for a question, the answer can be more general to the question itself - Is It Ethical to Disturb a Happy Illusion for the Sake of Reality?

Comment: It's a subjective decision. Should an atheist disturb a happy religious person? It might depend on context, and whether the receiver welcomes the new info.

Comment: The first Matrix was designed to make everyone happy but humans rejected the programming: https://youtu.be/9Qs3GlNZMhY?t=22. The Matrix and contemplation of my infantile ego ideal caused me to invent the concept of the giant dildo of society. First, in reality, society creates the giant dildo of society. Next, in reality, most humans are born into society, and learn to perform their roles as batteries in the giant dildo of society. If you remain a battery, or fight the social machine, either way society sucks your energy. How does one become happy and liberated from demands imposed by society?

Comment: All that *feels* important is that though the light is faint and diminshing with each passing second ... language and truth converge ... one last dance, one ... last ... dance, mademoiselle.

Comment: @AgentSmith Language will have to wine and dine truth before converging. Truth isn't easy. ;-)

Comment: @StevanV.Saban, Ok!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it morally right to disrupt someone's happiness to offer them the truth, even if it might cause distress?

This depends on one's moral philosophy. There are many moral philosophies, so from a canonical standpoint, there is no "right" answer. I can point you in the direction of [Voltaire's *The Good Brahmin*](https://www.philosophicalsociety.com/Archives/Voltaire%27s%20Story%20Of%20The%20Good%20Brahmin.htm) which discusses a very similiar theme, which is Would A Thinker Want a Happy Illusion for the Sake of Reality?

This is definitely in the neighborhood of subjectivity as user mcraeinich mentions in the comments:

> It's a subjective decision. Should an atheist disturb a happy religious person? It might depend on context, and whether the receiver welcomes the new info.

Perhaps an example. There are times when we morally intentionally cause distress to create resilience. For instance, in preparing a marine for combat, the US Marine Corps spends months intentionally distressing recruits. They scream and yell at them, deprive them of personal time, and often tell them the truth about the realities of war to disabuse enlistees of Hollywood's glorification.

Is it moral to cause distress for the sake of reality in this case? It would be immoral not to prepare a fighting force for the reality of combat which involves violence, death, and suffering, and the need to persist in the face of it. By refusing to cause distress and knowingly withholding reality from combat forces increases their odds of death. How would it possibly be moral to send sailors, soldiers, and marines to their death without adequate preparation?

So, the only factual answer possible here is it depends.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex ethical dilemma with reasonable arguments on both sides. Here is a summary of how different ethical perspectives may approach it:

Utilitarianism: Focused on maximizing happiness and minimizing suffering. Disturbing the illusion may not be justified if it decreases overall happiness. But the truth may lead to more authentic happiness for some. Situation-dependent.

Deontology: Focused on moral duties and rights. People have a right to the truth. Morpheus has a duty to inform, regardless of consequences. Lack of full disclosure violates informed consent.

Virtue ethics: Focused on character and ethical wisdom. Was Morpheus acting virtuously and with good intent? Does withholding full context reflect poor character/judgment? Case-by-case.

Existentialism: Focused on individual choice and responsibility. Morpheus respects agency by offering the truth/choice. But consent requires full context. Individuals must exercise freedom responsibly.

Pragmatism: Focused on what works best. Which decision leads to better outcomes? Truth has intrinsic and instrumental value but consequences matter. Balance is needed.